# SSRS - multiple values for TEXT data type parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am new to SSRS reports and have created a report based on a TEXT query:

```
select * from customers
where residence_state = :state -- oracle, or @state for SQL Server
```

This generated the parameters and I am able to give a value, such as 'CA' in the 'Report Parameter Properties - Available Values' Window. This works well, however, suppose that I want the :state(or @state) parameter to include 'CA' + 'AZ' + 'WA'. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

for MSSQL, change your query to

```
select * from customers
where residence_state in (@state)
```

This will make the parameter multivalued. And also, check the parameter properties in SSRS. Make sure

> Allow multiple values

is checked.

Answer (score 1):

For multi select parameters SSRS passes a comma delimited list of values. The code below is from a report where the parameter @program is a comma delimited set of uniqueidentifiers.

--I create a table variable

```
    declare @programs table
    (
        program_id uniqueidentifier
    )

    declare @myid uniqueidentifier
```

-- Then I parse the parameter values (which was declare as @program varchar(max)
-- as you can see I know the length of each parameter.
-- If you did use charindex to find the location of the next value
        while len(@program) > 0
        begin

```
        set @myid = convert(uniqueidentifier, left(@program, 36))
        set @program = substring(@program, 38, len(@program))
        --print @program

        insert @programs values(@myid)
    End
```

I hope this helps.